# Python Index Error using a for loop and list

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm a beginner and I wanted to code a simple game using turtle. The idea is to have one player and multiple enemies. When the player hits the enemy, the enemy changes position(random). But when I was creating a for loop for making multiple enemy objects, I got this index error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Testing", line 5, in <module>
    enemys[count].append(turtle.Turtle())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried using `range(0, len(enemys))` but then it doesn't do what I want, it won't make enemies since the length of `enemys` is zero. Here is my code :

```
import turtle    
maxEnemies = 6
enemys= []
for count in range(0, maxEnemies):
    enemys[count].append(turtle.Turtle())
    enemys[count].speed(0)
    enemys[count].shape("circle")
    enemys[count].color("red")
    enemys[count].penup()
    enemys[count].setpos(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300))
```

My expectations were that it would make 6 objects, all red, circle, etc.

Comment: so what's the expected output, a list of lists?

Comment: my exception was a list with turtle objects

Comment: change enemys[count].append(turtle.Turtle()) to enemys.insert(count,turtle.Turtle())

Comment: thank you very much, its working. but why

Comment: enemys is empty before so when you access enemys[count] it gives index error so you need to add element in order to use access by index

Comment: list[index] works only when there are elements in that index

Comment: oh thank you all, this helps me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, don't even need the `count` variable to be honest.

```
import turtle    
maxEnemies = 6
enemys= []
for _ in range(0, maxEnemies):
    enemy = turtle.Turtle()
    enemy.speed(0)
    enemy.shape('circle')
    enemy.color('red')
    enemy.penup()
    enemy.setpos(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300))
    enemys.append(enemy)
```

I don't know much about `turtle` so the syntax might be slightly off.

Answer (score 0):

`enemys[count].append()` will append a value to a list, since you use it on an element of the list `enemys` it will try to append to a list inside of `enemys`, but it's empty so it gives the error.
This is the correct code:

```
for count in range(0, maxEnemies):
    enemys.append(turtle.Turtle())
    enemys[count].speed(0)
    enemys[count].shape("circle")
    enemys[count].color("red")
    enemys[count].penup()
    enemys[count].setpos(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300))
```